# Changing Useragent For My Browser (coded using vb)

Tags: php, vb6

Hello i have a website and im trying to show this website for only my browser users. (my browser only shows my site too)

so i code this browser on visual basic express

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim userClickNavigate As Boolean = True

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        userClickNavigate = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
        If Not userClickNavigate Then
            userClickNavigate = True
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(e.Url, Nothing, Nothing, "User-Agent:Nokia-MIT-Browser/3.0")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        userClickNavigate = False
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://orenaksakal.org/demo2/", Nothing, Nothing, "User-Agent:Nokia-MIT-Browser/3.0")
    End Sub
End Class
```

this working really good on first. But i have in my php files. that code;

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Bu site Internet Exploreri desteklemiyor!");</script>';
    die();
```

and when i refresh page or go next link my user agent change is not working anymore.. turning back to IE..

how can i keep it always for my browser program?

Comment: HTTP_USER_AGENT can be faked.

Comment: thanks for warn me but its okay, i think no one will try it.. my webpage link is unique too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BeforeNavigate2 event you can intercept the browser request, cancel it and replace it with your own. Your call to the Navigate2 method will cause the event to fire again so you need to use a form level variable to check for and prevent recursion. I'm not sure what you're doing with the userClickNavigate flag so you may need to modify this to work with that.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const USER_AGENT = "User-Agent:Nokia-MIT-Browser/3.0" 'contant declaration of use agent
Private mblnRecursing As Boolean ' form level variable to prevent recursion

Private Sub Form_Load()

    WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "http://orenaksakal.org/demo2"

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim MyHeaders As Variant

    If (mblnRecursing = False) Then
        mblnRecursing = True
        Cancel = True
        MyHeaders = Headers & USER_AGENT
        WebBrowser1.Navigate2 URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, MyHeaders
    End If
    mblnRecursing = False

End Sub
```

Comment: @awdesign I ran this exact code with my own url so I know it works. Can you list the first 2 or 3 errors in the order you're getting them?

Comment: 2 errors i have now;
Error 1 'Option' statements must precede any declarations or 'Imports' statements.  



Error 2 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Navigate' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: @awdesign Are you using VB6 OR VB.NET?

Comment: @awdesign That is VB.NET. Because you tagged the question with VB6 my answer is in VB6 code. I will try to convert it for you.

Comment: oh, sorry for that. i install VB6 but now i have one error on "
Private Sub Form_Load()"  error is "variable is not defined"

Comment: @awdesign In VB6 Click on the Project - Components menu and then check Microsoft Internet Controls to add the WebBrowser control to the toolbox. You can then add the WebBrowser control to your form. By default it will be named WebBrowser1.

Comment: thank you so much its working now but after i click login program freezing :/